# I Want To use count_if based on my own parameters

Tags: c++, stl

Example i have a vector with integer value and i want to count no of elements in that vector that specifies my own runtime inputs.
exam vector has elemets 10 , 20 ,30,40
and at runtime i am taking input k; and want to count that satisfies >k

```
int ar[4]={10,44,36,14};
vector<int>shiva(ar,ar+4);

int k;
cin>>k;
cout<<*count_if(shiva.begin(),shiva.end(),myfun(k));
```

How to make a structure function ?
i want to print total no of elements that satisfies >k;

Comment: C++11 or earlier?

Comment: Use a lambda expression, see example here - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count

Answer (score 4):

You can solve this with a lambda function. The `count_if` function iterates through `vector` `shiva` and passes each element as `int i` into the lambda function. The lambda function checks whether `i` is larger than `k` and returns a `bool`. It knows the value of `k`, because we allow it to capture variable `k` by value, by specifying the capture as `[k]`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> shiva {10,44,36,14};

    int k;
    std::cin >> k;

    std::cout << std::count_if(shiva.begin(),
                               shiva.end(),
                               [k](int i) { return i > k; })
              << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It can be allowed Only in C++11 ,thanks for your valuable comment but how can i do that in current scenario

Comment: @ShivamPandey. Are you not allowed to use C++11?

Comment: no i cant use that ,i am getting trouble by creating structure type and using that.

Answer (score 3):

A lambda is just syntactic sugar for a struct with an overloaded operator ().

Here's a demo of how it can be done with C++98:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct greater_than
{
  int k;
  greater_than(int k) : k(k) {}
  bool operator () (int val) const {
    return val > k;
  }
};

int main()
{
  int ar[4] = { 10,44,36,14 };
  vector<int> shiva(ar, ar + 4);

  int k;
  cin >> k;
  cout << count_if(shiva.begin(), shiva.end(), greater_than(k)) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Why not declaring the struct in the scope of `main`?

Comment: So it can be reused outside of main, if needed. Either way will work, depends on the requirements.